# Order a dataset so that geom_path() connects the points in the same way as the human eye does

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Below is a reproducible example with what the desired output would look like.

```
# Example
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~x,~y,
  4,6,
  4.5,5.5,
  5,5,
  5.4,4.5,
  5.6,3.8,
  5.7,3,
  5.4,2.5,
  5,2,
  4.8,3)
# arbitrarily scaling because ordering needs to handle different x and y scales
df <- df %>% mutate(y = y*100)
# human eye draws the rough spiral connecting the points 
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() 
# geom_line moves along x-axis, not desired output
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() 
# geom_path does it right - exactly what I'm after
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_path()

# ...but I can't guarantee the df is going to start in the desired order:
df <- df %>% arrange(y) # arbitrarily sort by something else as orig order not guaranteed
# now geom_path doesn't work
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_path()

#Q: how to go from an unordered df to a line plot with geom_path() that matches the dots in 
# the same way as the human eye when just given the points.
```

I think I want a function that takes an original dataset, orders it like the human eye would, then can be plotted using geom_path(). I already have tried one method, that I've called the "second_min", but it doesn't work:

```
second_min_func <- function(df){
  
  # try scaling (though not finished as need to scale back to orig axis after ordered)
  df <- df %>% scale() %>% as_tibble()
  
  # nest the dataframe back onto itself so can rowwise perform operations on all data
  df2 <- df  %>% 
    mutate(orig_order = row_number(),
           temp=1) %>% 
    left_join(nest(df, data=everything()) %>% mutate(temp=1),
              by="temp") %>%
    select(-temp)
  
  df3 <- df2 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(
      # euclidean distance for each point against all others
      vec = list((x-df$x)^2 + (y-df$y)^2)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    group_by(orig_order) %>% 
    mutate(
      # the first minimum is 0 always as it's the point itself
      second_min = which(vec[[1]]==vec[[1]][topn(vec[[1]],decreasing=FALSE)][2])
    ) %>%
    select(x,y,orig_order,second_min)
  
  df3 <- df3 %>% arrange(second_min)
  return(df3)
}

# not desired output!
ggplot(second_min_func(df),aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a well defined question. If the only rule is "like the human eye does it" that's not really specific to be able to program a solution and test it. Who knows if different eyes interpret the data differently. Eyes are often misled by poorly designed graphs or incorrect assumptions about data. If you want to connect lines, your data should determine the order in which they are connected. Use a variable to keep track of the sequence before rearranging rows.

Comment: Thanks, and you may well be right. In the real-life example prompting this data, there are many points and I think the the 'human eye' way of connecting them is clear, but I accept the comment.

The problem is there is no predetermined sequence to connect the rows, the data only comes out with the 2 variables. 

My attempted second_min_func tried to connect each point to it's closest one, as I thought that should do it, but the function isn't working as intended. The column second_min is the variable trying to keep track as you say

Comment: Well, connecting points with minimal distance is a much different request that connecting them like the human eye would. Perhaps you can clarify that in your quesiton.

Comment: I'm not sure minimal distance is the right answer, but it was my idea to try and solve the issue which is as I posed it.

Answer (score 4):

It's late and I have a half assed solution that I wanted to post before going to bed. I'd propose to compute a k-nearest neighbour graph, find the shortest path in the minimum spanning tree and use the visited vertices as the order.

Just showing that I messed up the order properly:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(igraph)

df <- tribble(
  ~x,~y,
  4,6,
  4.5,5.5,
  5,5,
  5.4,4.5,
  5.6,3.8,
  5.7,3,
  5.4,2.5,
  5,2,
  4.8,3)
# arbitrarily scaling because ordering needs to handle different x and y scales
df <- df %>% mutate(y = y*100)

# Random order
set.seed(42)
df <- df[sample(seq_len(nrow(df))),]

# Show order is scrambled
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path()
```

[image]

Approach is as follows:

```r
# Rescale
df <- df %>%
  mutate(x = rescale(x)) %>%
  mutate(y = rescale(y))

# Euclidean distance
d <- dist(df[, c("x", "y")], method = "euclidean")
d <- as.matrix(d)

# Find k nearest neighbours
k <- 2
diag(d) <- Inf # Don't allow self to be nearest neighbour
nn <- apply(d, 1, rank, ties.method = "random")
nn <- apply(nn, 2, function(x) {which(x <= k)})

# Make graph from nn list
elist <- cbind(rep(as.numeric(colnames(nn)), each = nrow(nn)),
               as.vector(nn))
g <- graph_from_edgelist(elist, directed = FALSE)
E(g)$weight <- d[elist]

# Calculate longest shortest path (?) through minimum spanning tree
g <- mst(g)
path <- all_shortest_paths(g, from = V(g))
path <- path$res[which.max(lengths(path$res))][[1]]

# Order is the vertices the shortest path visits
order <- as.integer(path)

# Reorder scrambled df
ggplot(df[order,], aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_path()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

It works on this particular dataset with this seed for this particular `k` and I have no clue how well this generalises to more challenging datasets. But at least it's something.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is minimize distances between points, then one possible solution is to find the minimal Hamiltonian path through all the points. In that case it's a lot like the Traveling Salesman Problem so you can use the `TSP` package to help with this. Here's a helper function

```
library(TSP)
minimize_distances <- function(df) {
  tsp <- insert_dummy(TSP(dist(df)), label = "cut")
  tour <- solve_TSP(tsp, 
                   method="cheapest_insertion")
  path <- cut_tour(tour, "cut")
  df[as.numeric(path), ]
}
```

which you can run with

```
ggplot(minimize_distances(df)) + 
  aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

Comment: I knew there was a smarter way than whatever I improvised!